# Showing jsf panels without visual effect of nested components

Tags: java, jsf, user-interface, primefaces

I am creating a website with the following template.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
Header
----------------------------------------------------------------
left menu | Content                                 |right menu|
          |                                         |          |
          |                                         |          |
          |                                         |          |
          |                                         |          |
          |                                         |          |
----------------------------------------------------------------
Footer
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

In the header, I have a drop down menu.  When an option is selected from the drop down menu, the left menu component updates, using Ajax, to show two panels with checkbox items.  See screen shot in the link below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxc9y.jpg

When you select one, none, or many of the items and click submit, the content component of the layout updates with a message.

My website works functionally: the layout is fine, drop down menu works, content updates, etc.  **My question is how to get rid of the visually unappealing effect of the nested panels in the left menu component of the layout.**  If you look closely at the image, you can see the outline of the layout unit with id="west" (outermost), panel with id="leftMenu" (middle) and panels with id="leftMenuA" and "leftMenuB" (innermost). Refer to the code block below for id's.

```
    <p:layoutUnit id="west" position="west" size="250" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
        <p:panel id="leftMenu">
            <p:panel id="leftMenu1A" rendered="#{leftMenuBean.leftMenu1}" header="North" toggleable="true" closable="true" toggleSpeed="500" closeSpeed="500" widgetVar="panelA">
                <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{leftMenu1Bean.selectedServersA}" layout="pageDirection">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{leftMenu1Bean.serversA}" />
                </p:selectManyCheckbox>
            </p:panel>

            <p:panel id="leftMenu1B" rendered="#{leftMenuBean.leftMenu1}" header="East" toggleable="true" closable="true" toggleSpeed="500" closeSpeed="500" widgetVar="panelB">
                <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{leftMenu1Bean.selectedServersB}" layout="pageDirection">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{leftMenu1Bean.serversB}" />
                </p:selectManyCheckbox>
            </p:panel>

            <p:separator />

            <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="content" rendered="#{leftMenuBean.leftMenu1}" action="#{leftMenu1Bean.getOtherInfo}" />
        </p:panel>
    </p:layoutUnit>
```

I want my page to look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/flljU.jpg
Notice how in the left menu component of the layout, only the outline of the layout unit with id="west" is visible.

I appreciate any suggestions you may have to offer.  Thank you so much!

Comment: You probably have to change a CSS property for a class. I would suggest you to use a browser developer plugin like Firebug to inspect the HTML code to find the CSS `class` which needs to be adapted.